# How can I create in external button in Angular Timer?

Tags: angularjs, timer

How can I create in external button to save the current time to put in my database in Angular Timer ?

Comment: you are assuming that people know the module you are using ...what timer?

Comment: my bad...this is the link for de Module...http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/